# brew update (homebrew) take a lot of time to run

Tags: macos, homebrew

I am a new mac user,
and I just installed HomeBrew to set up my computer for business use,
but every time I run a `brew` command,
`brew update`
is started automatically and takes a lot of time,
I have time to do what I want before it works!
please be indulgent with me and teach me a way to solve my problem
I want to clarify that I do not have a network problem because everything works correctly on this side.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following config into your shell init files. (`.bash_profile` for Bash, `.zshrc` for ZSH)

```sh
export HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1
```

> `HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE`: If set, Homebrew will not auto-update before running brew install, brew upgrade or brew tap.